Grid formatting for decimal numbers and a heading
I would like to format a grid in such a way that there is a heading with centre alignment and the following rows with decimal alignment. My code for this is
    Grid[Join[{{"column1", "column2"}, {100.234, 1000.12}, {1.2, 1.345}}],
         Alignment -> {None, {None, {"."}}},
         Background -> {None, {LightBlue, {None}}},
         Frame -> All]

This gives

Which is not what I want. The only method which I know of is to use PaddedForm but that seems obscure and requires further coding.
Is partial decimal formatting possible?

why not just Grid[{{"column1", "column2"},   {100.234, 1000.12},   {1.2, 1.345}}, Frame -> All, Spacings -> {1, 1},   Alignment -> Center]  https://i.sstatic.net/mLoXCQJD.png  or do did you mean you want to align on decimal point?

You can choose ´Alignment -> "."´ for all the entries and specify the headers using e.g.: Item["column1", Alignment -> "Center"]
Grid[Join[{{Item["column1", Alignment -> "Center"], 
    Item["column2", Alignment -> "Center"]}, {100.234, 1000.12}, {1.2,
     1.345}}], Alignment -> ".", 
 Background -> {None, {LightBlue, {None}}}, Frame -> All]


